# symfony2 validation groups - just one group works

Tags: validation, symfony

this is my form:

```
$forumuser = new Forumuser();
        $passwordform = $this->createFormBuilder($forumuser, array('validation_groups' => array('userSettings')))
            ->add('passwordold', 'password', array('attr' => array('autocomplete' => 'off'), 'required' => false, 'error_bubbling' => true, 'property_path' => false))
            ->add('password', 'repeated', array(   'type' => 'password',
                                                        'invalid_message' => 'user.myprofile.password.repeat',
                                                        'options' => array('attr' => array('autocomplete' => 'off'), 'required' => false, 'error_bubbling' => true)                                                    
                                                    )
            )
            ->getForm();
```

And this is the attribute with validationannotations in ForumUser.class:

```
/**
     * @var string $password
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=200, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="forumuser.password.notblank", groups={"userRegister", "userSettings"})
     * @Assert\MinLength(limit="4", message="forumuser.password.minlength", groups={"userRegister", "userSettings"})
     */
    private $password;
```

I would like to use the group **userSettings** but after binding the $passwordform->getErrors() is empty. When i'm using the **userRegister** group all other attributes are validated. It means, everything i do, the password attribute is not validated.

Does anybody know what i'm doing wrong?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to define on form type , diiferent group name  like this 

public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => '',
            'cascade_validation' => true,

            'validation_groups' => array('user_settings'),
        );
    }
```

same like at other one .